# What is the purpose of the Name parameter in HttpPostAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, actionmethod

I am seeing the following code being applied in .net core action methods:

```
[HttpPost("MyAction", Name = "MyAction")]
public IActionResult MyAction()
{
    // some code here
}
```

What is the purpose of the "Name" parameter in the HttpPost attribute?

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply and details. Does that mean that I can access the end point with both the URLs: https://servername.com/ControllerName/ActionName as well as  https://servername.com/ControllerName/NameAttributeValue  ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Name` property is used for **[Url Generation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.0#url-generation)**. It has nothing to do with routing! You can omit it almost all the time.

Add the following code to your controller and you will get the "Aha!":

```
[HttpGet("qqq", Name = "xxx")]
public string yyy()
{
   return "This is the action yyy";
}

[HttpGet("test")]
public string test()
{
    var url = Url.Link("xxx", null);  //Mine is https://localhost:44384/api/qqq
    return $"The url of Route Name xxx is {url}";
}
```

The `Name` property in the first action, when used, for example, to generate a url, is merely used to reference the action `yyy`. In my set up, invoking `/api/test` returns the string `The url of Route Name xxx is https://localhost:44384/api/qqq`.

Action `yyy` is reachable by the *route* `.../qqq`, the first parameter passed to the `HttpGet` attribute constructor.

Answer (score 4):

[From the source](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Routing/IRouteTemplateProvider.cs,088178d33bca6fda)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the route name. The route name can be used to generate a link using a specific route, instead
    ///  of relying on selection of a route based on the given set of route values.
    /// </summary>
    string Name { get; }
```

Example usage; If you have two methods with the same name that take different parameters, you can use Name parameter to differentiate Action Names.

Comment: And how to call them why no url example?

Answer (score 4):

From [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.0#route-name) :

> Route names can be used to generate a URL based on a specific route. Route names have no impact on the URL matching behavior of routing and are only used for URL generation. Route names must be unique application-wide.

It can be used to generate a URL based on a specific route . For example , route defines like :

```
[HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetContact")]
public IActionResult GetById(string id)
{
    var contact = contactRepository.Get(id);
    if (contact == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return new ObjectResult(contact);
}
```

You can use `CreatedAtRoute` method to return with the content of newly contact as well as the URI of it. The `CreatedAtRoute` method will based on the route name "GetContact" and id to generate the URI:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create([FromBody] Contact contact)
{
    if (contact == null)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
    contactRepository.Add(contact);
    return CreatedAtRoute("GetContact", new { id = contact.ContactId }, contact);
}
```